# Wubi-installed ubuntu won't allow me to execute executable files

Tags: mount, permissions, wubi, compiling, executable

I'm trying to run executable files on Ubuntu, but it's not working, although the exact same executable file works fine on others' machines, which are also running Ubuntu 12.04 like me. Based on this, I asked a question here: [Executing compiled file on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940763/executing-compiled-file-on-ubuntu-invalid-or-incomplete-multibyte-or-wide-char)

But now I realize the issue isn't in my compiled file. Because I wrote a very simple .cpp file and tested it, but Ubuntu still didn't run it.

This is my simple test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
 printf ("Hello, this test worked!");
return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled it:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o test test.cpp
```

And then tried to run it:

```
./test
```

But I get an error:

```
bash: ./test: Permission denied
```

So I try with sudo:

```
sudo ./test
```

which asks me for my user password, which I give, but then it says:

```
sudo: ./test: command not found
```

When I run:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

I get this:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

When I run

```
df .
```

It says:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      17596475 6112377  11484098  35% /
```

Running

```
ls -l
```

gives me:

```
-rw------- 1 asaaki asaaki 8380 Apr 8 18:16 test
```

And running

```
umask
```

gives me

```
0002
```

I've tried

```
sudo chmod +x test
```

and then tried

```
./test
```

But I still get permission denied.
How can I run executable files at all? Do I need to uninstall ubuntu and install it with different configuration options or something? Isn't there are a way to circumvent this problem?